# Machine Learning detecting random string

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I do apologies in advance if something similar has been posted but from the research I've done I can't find anything specific.

I'm currently looking at http://scikit-learn.org and the content here looks great but I'm confused what type I should be using for my problem.

I want to able to have 2 labels.

```
**Suspicious**  
1hbn34uqrup7a13t
qmr30zoyswr21cdxolg
1qmqnbetqx

**Not-Suspicious**
cheesemix
reg526
animato12
```

What type of machine learning algorithm could I feed the data in above as to teach it what I'd class as suspicious through supervised learning?

I'm leaning towards classification but there are so many models to choose from my slightly lost.

Comment: Since you have only one example in each set, it's very hard to know what you're trying to discriminate.  What features make the first suspicious, but the second acceptable?  Do you even know, yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step in such machine learning problems is to think about the "features". You can't use e.g. a linear classifier directly on these strings. Thus, you have to extract some meaningful features that describe the string. In computer vision, these features are often edges, corner points, SIFT features. You basically have to options:

1. Design features yourself.
2. Learn the features.

**1)** This is the "classical" machine learning approach: you manually design a list of representative features, which you can extract from your input data. In your case, you could start with e.g.

- length of the string
- number of different characters
- number of special characters
- something about the sorting?
- ...

That will give you a vector of numbers for each string. Now, you can use any of the classifiers from scikit-learn to classify the data. You can start choosing your algorithm with the help of [this flowchart](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html). You should start with a simple model, e.g. a linear model (e.g. linear SVM). If performance is not sufficient, use a more complex model (e.g. SVM with kernels), or rethink your choice of features.

**2)** This is the "modern" approach, which is gaining more and more popularity. Designing the features is a crucial step in 1) and it requires good knowledge of your data. Now, by using a deep neural network, you can feed your raw data (the string) into the network, and let the network learn such "features" itself. This, however, requires a large amount of labeled training data, and a lot of processing power (GPUs).

LSTM networks are todays state-of-the-art in natural language processing and similar tasks. LSTMs would be well suited to your tasks, as the input can be of variable length.

**tl;dr**: Either design features yourself and use a classifier of your choice, or dive into deep neural networks and let a network learn both the features and the classification.